# Is it possible to store local storage data in mongodb through angular?

Tags: angular, mongodb, local-storage

I stored a username in local storage and I'm trying to store it in mongoDB. Is this possible at all or should I find another way? I specified localStorage.getItem(JSON.stringify("Users")) to the 'sellname' field but it didn't work and saved the field as null instead. I have no idea what I'm doing, please help.

Service.ts

```
export class DetailsService {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  quotesUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000/api/quotes";


  getAllQuotes() {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.quotesUrl);
  }

  insertQuote(product: string, newdetails: string, minbid: number, currentbid: number, bidno: number, sellname: string) {
    return this.http.post<any[]>(this.quotesUrl, {
      'product': product, 
      'details': newdetails,
      'minbid': minbid,
      'currentbid' : currentbid,
      'bidno' : bidno,
      'sellname' : sellname
    });
  }
```

component.ts

```
export class ShareComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Product Details';
  quotes: any = [];
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private detailsService: DetailsService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    // Retrieve quotes from the API
    this.detailsService.getAllQuotes().subscribe(quotes => {
      this.quotes = quotes;
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      product: '',
      details: '',
      minbid: '',
      currentbid: '',
      bidno: 0,
      sellname: localStorage.getItem(JSON.stringify("Users"))
    });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this.detailsService.insertQuote(this.myForm.value.product, 
                                    this.myForm.value.details,
                                    this.myForm.value.minbid,
                                    this.myForm.value.currentbid,
                                    this.myForm.value.bidno,
                                    this.myForm.value.sellname).subscribe(results => {
        location.reload();
      });
  }
```

component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" style="text-align:center; font-family:monospace;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1>Please input your product details.</h1>
              <h2>Product Name:<input class="input-field" formControlName="product" id="product" placeholder=" Product" size="50"></h2>
              <h2>Product Details:<input class="input-field" formControlName="details" id="details" placeholder=" Details" size="50"></h2>
              <h2>Minimum Bid:<input class="input-field" formControlName="minbid" id="minbid" placeholder=" Minimum Bid" size="50"></h2>
              <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you set the position for `JSON.stringify` wrong. Second: You need `JSON.parse`. The **localStorage** save all as `string` so you need convert it back to `JSON` Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      product: '',
      details: '',
      minbid: '',
      currentbid: '',
      bidno: 0,
      sellname: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Users"))
    });
  }
```

If you "set" the sellname, use this:

```
localStorage.setItem("Users", JSON.stringify(someData));
```

Your question about MongoDB: Yes, you can save it inside Mongo. But it is not the best way. Think: a **JSON Web Token** as example will be send from the frontend to the backend for auth, so you can get it from Mongo before you logged in.
So you're right to store this things like username, tokens and so on in localStorage.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
However, it saved it like:
      sellname: object
            username: 'John'
Is there a way to save just John? so that it'll look like
sellname: 'John'

Comment: If my answer help you can rate it and mark it as answer, too. If you wanna only save the name so you can do it simple: `localStorage.setItem("username", yourObject.name);` Then you don't need JSON.parse and JSON.stringify.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but doing `localStorage.setItem("username", this.user);` saves it in local storage as [object Object] which triggers an error when I set the field as `sellname: localStorage.getItem("username")`

Comment: I dont know where you object comes from. If it the form? So `localStorage.setItem("username", this.myForm.value.sellname);` or set it directly: `localStorage.setItem("username", "Paul");` or from variable: `localStorage.setItem("username", username);`